# How to write SQlite Query For multiple rows update

Tags: ios, sqlite

plz check the query is not working for me if any corrections edit it .Which will helpfull to me .

```
const char *TimedEventQuery=[ @"update table1  set EndTime = ?, Duration = ?,   where EndTime is null  and eventType = 2 or 3" UTF8String];
```

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

```
const char *TimedEventQuery= "update table1  set EndTime = ?, Duration = ?   where EndTime is null  and (eventType = 2 or  eventType = 3)";
```

1. Just use a C string
2. You had an extra comma just before "where"
3. Your "or" condition was incorrect.